# Unknown IP trying to sign in to my phpmyadmin

Tags: hacking, phpmyadmin

I am very worried.
I have a little web server hosting a PhpMyAdmin page (in which they are some important databases). Yesterday, I posted a full new webpage on my server (but a very simple HTML and stylesheet page no something that the world just does not care about). I told this to no body. I just went to my site with my mother's computer to show her the look of the site. And, since yesterday there are very very strange IP that accessed my webserver (I see them on apache2 access logs).

Some tried to access directories that even does not exist :
[Here is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2VC4.png)

What are these directories /home, /login/, /vpn ??? As you can see, obviously, they returned 404 to the client but why did he try to access this ?
And, actually this is not very important as some other IP tried like 40 times to access PhpMyAdmin.
[Here is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xALq.png)

And this is only like 50% of the IP of this guy.
As you can see I tried all passwords possible. Fortunately, I am not dumb (lol) and I put a strong password (12 characters with numbers, captions..) but what if one day this hacker one day ? Because I use the same password on all my accounts on website (except emails Fortunately). 
I tried to see where does this guy come from. So i searched on iplocation.com 
[Here are the results :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkylv.png)

I have fail2ban installed on my server but it only works on ssh and apache. I also looked for putting a .htpasswd file but I think this is only for apache pages.

I am really stressed because of my server is very very small (quad core 1.5GHz and 4Gb RAM) and of course it cannot handle any DDoS or whatever else.

Whan can I do ? Is setting a fail2ban / second password security layer a good idea ?
I also use this server as VPN and I ssh often. Do you think the hacker could be monitoring my activity and catch passwords I fill to access VPN or SSH ?

This post i very long and my english is horrible so thanks if took your time to consider my problem

Any help is welcome

Clement

Answer (score 5):

Part of having a public-facing server is that massive number of infected machines are constantly trying a huge number of possible resources in the hope of exploiting something. They'll try a lot of common URLs (such as `/admin/`) in the hopes of finding vulnerable software. This is all automated, constant, and usually come from many sources. It's unlikely that you're the result of an intentional targeted attack. You're likely to see this scan from that particular IP address now, and something similar in a few hours, days, or months from a different IP address. It is possible that you've inherited an IP address that some particular person wants to attack, but the more likely explanation is simply that your server is online and these massive sets of computers are attempting to attack every server they can find.

There are some common sense tips you can use to reduce your vulnerability. Enabling two-factor authentication (which phpMyAdmin supports), running the least number of services possible (as in, don't run an FTP daemon if you don't need to, etc), and regularly updating all public-facing software are all things that can help. I'm not sure about the effectiveness of fail2ban; some people say that it's good because it blocks repeated attempts and can reduce the number of attempts to hack your system, others might argue that since the attacks come from a distributed source, that blocking the IP addresses one at a time is ineffective. Personally, I like security in layers and think anything to reduce the effectiveness of an attack can help make my system more secure.

Regarding phpMyAdmin specifically, I have some thoughts. On one of my servers, I do not allow phpMyAdmin to be accessed from the public internet. I configure nginx to listen only for local connections, then I use an SSH tunnel to connect to my server, treating it as a jump box so nginx sees the incoming connection as being from localhost. This way, I'm not exposing phpMyAdmin directly to the internet. Again, I'm working in layers; if I leave my phpMyAdmin exposed then an attack could try to brute-force the password. If you do leave phpMyAdmin exposed, you should remove the anonymous MySQL user and audit all the user accounts to make sure they are needed and have good passwords. You might want to enable the two-factor authentication in phpMyAdmin.

I also recommend against running VNC (or RDP) from a public-facing interface. I feel you should tunnel those connections through an SSH tunnel or VPN. While there are many implementations of each, and I am not knowledgeable enough about the details of any to comment here about any specific solution, in general those protocols historically have been a high risk service.

You asked about fail2ban and said it only works on SSH and Apache. That's fine; do you have any other services running? Your phpMyAdmin is served through Apache (or whatever web server you're running) and most of the other pages in your log section are nonexistent, so that end of things look pretty safe. If you're running other services, you should look in to securing those properly, but so far you've only mentioned SSH and Apache and if you take steps to secure those you'll be in much better shape than some other servers out there.

Changing ports is another option you could consider, such as running SSH on port 9999 or VNC on port 10000 (just to make some up). These nonstandard ports will help somewhat with reducing the amount of traffic you're getting, but from my experience are generally not a very strong line of defense. The main reason is that attackers are probably running full port scans, rather than just trying common ports. They can scan all of your available ports, and this would only the attackers putting forth the least amount of effort. Some people feel it's another layer of security. I'm personally indifferent about this method.

Another technique you could consider is called [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking). The quick version of that is your server would not accept connection attempts for services (such as SSH or VNC) until you first access a specific port or series of ports. It's like a secret knock used to get your server to allow you in; to attackers the VNC port would look closed but when you access it in the right sequence, you'll be able to connect. Port knocking can be another tool in the layered approach to security. Configuring it requires some effort, but the benefit is that your server can avoid connection attempts from attackers on most protocols (of course, things you want the public to find, such as HTTP, would be exempt from the port-knocking rules).

You really should have unique, strong passwords for each service. You can use a password manager or notebook to keep track of them, but reusing passwords between services is generally a bad security practice.

One more thing, I'm a huge fan of disabling SSH password login entirely and relying on keys based authentication. The cryptography involved with guessing a private key is much more difficult than brute forcing a password. Using key-based authentication and disabling the password login will be a big step to making your SSH access more secure.

Comment: Before everything, thanks for your answer. As I expected and like you said, I check today's log of apache access and yes some other IP tried to access the same URL /admin... that does not exist on my server. Also, another IP that found I had PhpMyAdmin tried to sign in again with bruteforce attack. One thing I am not stressed about anymore is that he tries to login as root and I did not enable root login. I check from where were these new IPs adresses coming. Strangely, two of them come from Oracle Corporation and one of yesterday came from Microsoft Azure... These are big companies

Comment: Why they do that ? || My server is currently attached to a DNS with a dynamin IP (no-ip.com). Do you think it is a good idea that I change my DNS and I reboot my router to have a new IP (I am really bad in English tell me if I need to clarify). Actually, I am just as you. I like the method of secureing something with a different security and access layouts. I will try to enable 2FA on PhpMyAdmin but I took a look at it and it seems to be hard to enable. For your idea of only accessing PhpMyAdmin from localhost, I must say this idea is just insane. I will try to enable it in some hours

Comment: I will tell you if it works but thanks because I think this security layer is very good. || Yes I have other running services. I have OpenVPN, VNC Server and I think that's it. Is my server more vulenrable with these services ? About the SSH login.... When I first set up my server (running debian), yes only the private key ssh access was enabled. But I must say, I did not understand anything in how this private and public key method works. Really, I was completely lost so I preferred enabling the SSH password access but yes of course, key is more secure. I could enable it I would do it.Thanks!

Comment: Alas changing DNS does nothing towards hacking attempts on your server, as it is all based on IP address. It is rather trivial for a hacker with access to a server farm to scan **all public IPv4 addresses on the Internet** and find out which ones has a webserver running on port 80 (http) or 443 (https). Heard about distributed scanning that can do the scanning in a matter of hours. The same can't be done with IPv6, but it will be years before that will be the default protocol for the Internet.

Comment: You can configure the Apache HTTP server to serve different content if accessed by IP rather than by its proper DNS name (even serve different TLS/SSL certificate when the SNI isn't the correct one). Doesn't help for tagetted attacks but does help for random scans of IP ranges.

Comment: I recommend against exposing VNC (or RDP) on a publicly available server. It's much better to use port knocking or tunnel such connections over an encrypted connection.

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard yes but like I said I still have a dynamic IP address and just a DNS attached to it. So if change my DNS and I reboot my router (so the IP is reset), I would "disappear" from hackers list since both my DNS and IP changed no ?

Comment: First I must say thanks @ibennetch. Now PhpMyAdmin shows 403 when I try to access it from something different of localhost. I am much less stressed now. They were two type of hackers trying to break my site : those who know I had PHP (and know they cannot do anything more ; is that true ?) and those who were trying random URL. My principal fear was about PHP since (I know I said it like 10 times) I use the same password everywhere. || For the "other hackers". Is it dangerous they try to access random URL. Is returning even 404 error CPU demanding. Now my last fear : could my server be DDoSed ?

Comment: @ibennetch my VNC is protected of course by a password. What is port knocking ? (I got this server not a very long time ago so sorry I am not an expert ;) And yes the connection is encrypted. || As the answer mentionned below, I should change my ports. I already did this for SSH and now I have done it for VNC. Do you think it is ok ?

Comment: @cl.ement05 I've edited to add some information about port knocking and changed ports in my answer. No need to apologize about not knowing, that's what we're all here for. I should have added more about that to begin with.

Comment: @cl.ement05: Regarding dynamic ip - have you verified that your ip changes regularly? Because it is not uncommon for ISP to assign a static ip through dhcp or having a long lease making it a de facto static ip. Speaking from experience: One of my former ISPs changed only my ip address during network maintenance, making my ip address de facto static for about 3-6 month at a time. But as I have hintet earlier: I would not rely on dynamic IPv4 address as a security feature. Only in IPv6, because it can be setup to change every 15 min or so.

Comment: @ibennetch about the port knocking unfortunately I am on a Windows Environment and I also often SSH my server with my Android phone. And 99% of the apps to knock ports only exist on Linux. But I just got a heat attack. On apache2 log, something just appearead. Someone accesses the / page which like I said I so simple HTML code. But the thing is that after that is it written (github masscan) and when I went to github to see what was that I saw that this was a massive scan tool. Heeelp !! What can I do. I have strong passwords but my server cannot handle buteforces attacks. I am very scared !!

Comment: Yes @LasseMichaelMølgaard actually I live in France and my ISP resets my IP every time I reboot my router so.. It is very easy to me change my IP

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use key authentication instead to strengthen the SSH ultimately.

Here is a few alternative to alleviate the attack:
1. Use port transfer by firewall to camouflage your ssh and vpn port. For example, 3390->22, and then ban 22. Unsophisticated attacker would find that ssh is no longer at its port and give up wasting time to attack your hardened server.

2. Install fail2ban if you do not want to use key autherization.
3. Ban root login, and instead create an user you are familiar with - your pets' name, for example. The hacker would encounter double guessing problem instead of single guessing problem. The difficulty grows exponentially.

However these two are NOT directly related to your problem. The main problem for you is if the hacker can utilize PHP adiminstration as a step stone to gain root privilege, without knowing your root password. You have to carefully examine the user PHP uses - if it uses root then the hacker's strategy would suceed once he breeches PHP system.

Traditional strategy includes downgrading the privilage, allocate a user with limited privilage to do the job, for example. OpenVPN has the option to drop to "nobody" once it sets up tunneling and routing which only root user is allowed to do. You have to study if there is possibility that PHP enables you to do this.

Another alternative is to use SELinux, which blocks suspecious action even if PHP is breeched. PHP should do its job, and anything beyond that is forbidden.

Comment: Fortnunately, my SSH port is a little bit different than the default one. Instead of port 22, it is port 922. || Like I commented in the upper post, luckily, I did not enable root login. The user name I currently sign in with is "pi" (and of course I have other user names but these are hard to guess). But one point I am worried about is that the IP adress are different. This means (and of course) hackers talk each other about sites to target. My server is absolutely not capable of handling an attack from like 100 IP at one time. || No the user I use with PHP is pi but actually "pi" user

Comment: is a sudoer user... || About SELinux is it an app or a full operating system ? When you describe it like that, to me that's the best solution ever but there are always disadvantages. Where are them ? Do you think installing SELinux could solve my problem ? Actually, my fear is not totally that the hacker gains root access but more that the password I use to sign in is the password I use everywhere else (eg on Stack Exchange but also on Apple ID, PayPal and some other apps that do really matter..

Comment: SELinux was default extra-layer protection on CentOS. You should change for another password.

Answer (score 0):

After you secured phpmyadmin you can use a jail like mine below to ban all other creeps. You can just modify it to meet your needs

```
[Definition]

badreqcustom =.*mysql.*|.*backup.*|.*wlwmanifest.*|.*xmlrpc.*|.*sleep.*|.*benchmark.*|.*when.*|.*then.*|.*schema.*|.*else.*|.*author.*

badreq = .*sql.*|.*adminer.*|.*alert.*|.*union.*|.*select.*|.*where.*|.*fetch.*|.*proxy.*

failregex = (?i)^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).(?:%(badreq)s|%(badreqcustom)s).*".*".*".*".*".*$
ignoreregex = (?i)^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).*(madmin|uid|gclid|/blog/|/photographers-directory/|/amasty_acart).*"$
```